# Wpf Datagrid Max Rows

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am currently working with data grid where I only want to allow the user to enter UP TO 20 rows of data before making CanUserAddRows to false.

I made a dependency property on my own datagrid (that derives from the original one). I tried using the event "`ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged`" and check for row count in there and if row count = max rows, then make can user add row = false (I get an exception for that saying i'm not allow to change it during "Add Row".

I was wondering if there is a good way on implementing this ....

Thanks and Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a subclassed `DataGrid` with a `MaxRows` Dependency Property. The things to note about the implementation is if the `DataGrid` is in edit mode and `CanUserAddRows` is changed an `InvalidOperationException` will occur *(like you mentioned in the question)*.

> **InvalidOperationException**
>   'NewItemPlaceholderPosition' is not
>   allowed during a transaction begun by
>   'AddNew'.

To workaround this, a method called `IsInEditMode` is called in `OnItemsChanged` and if it returns true we subscribe to the event `LayoutUpdated` to check `IsInEditMode` again.

Also, if `MaxRows` is set to 20, it must allow 20 rows when `CanUserAddRows` is True, and 19 rows when False (to make place for the `NewItemPlaceHolder` which isn't present on False).

It can be used like this

```
<local:MaxRowsDataGrid MaxRows="20"
                       CanUserAddRows="True"
                       ...>
```

**MaxRowsDataGrid**

```
public class MaxRowsDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxRowsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaxRows",
                                    typeof(int),
                                    typeof(MaxRowsDataGrid),
                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(0, MaxRowsPropertyChanged));
    private static void MaxRowsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MaxRowsDataGrid maxRowsDataGrid = source as MaxRowsDataGrid;
        maxRowsDataGrid.SetCanUserAddRowsState();
    }
    public int MaxRows
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaxRowsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxRowsProperty, value); }
    }

    private bool m_changingState;
    public MaxRowsDataGrid()
    {
        m_changingState = false;
    }
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        if (IsInEditMode() == true)
        {
            EventHandler eventHandler = null;
            eventHandler += new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                if (IsInEditMode() == false)
                {
                    SetCanUserAddRowsState();
                    LayoutUpdated -= eventHandler;
                }
            });
            LayoutUpdated += eventHandler;
        }
        else
        {
            SetCanUserAddRowsState();
        }
    }
    private bool IsInEditMode()
    {
        IEditableCollectionView itemsView = Items;
        if (itemsView.IsAddingNew == false && itemsView.IsEditingItem == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }        
    // This method will raise OnItemsChanged again 
    // because a NewItemPlaceHolder will be added or removed
    // so to avoid infinite recursion a bool flag is added
    private void SetCanUserAddRowsState()
    {
        if (m_changingState == false)
        {
            m_changingState = true;
            int maxRows = (CanUserAddRows == true) ? MaxRows : MaxRows-1;
            if (Items.Count > maxRows)
            {
                CanUserAddRows = false;
            }
            else
            {
                CanUserAddRows = true;
            }
            m_changingState = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I am an adept of K.I.S.S. To reduce the amount of lines required to do the job and keep it simple, use the following:

```
    private void MyDataGrid_LoadingRow( object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e )
    {
        // The user cannot add more rows than allowed
        IEditableCollectionView itemsView = this.myDataGrid.Items;
        if( this.myDataGrid.Items.Count == max_RowCount + 1 && itemsView.IsAddingNew == true )
        {
            // Commit the current one added by the user
            itemsView.CommitNew();

            // Once the adding transaction is commit the user cannot add an other one
            this.myDataGrid.CanUserAddRows = false;
        }
    }
```

Simple and compact ;0)

Comment: What happens when they delete a row and then try and add another one?