# select first 20 rows from a datatable

Tags: winforms, datagridview, dataset

My problem is simple: I have a DataSet with few DataTables inside a WinForms solution targeting .NET 2.0. I need to bind a DataGridView to one of the datatables and need to be able to filter the contents of the datatable.
It's very simple to bind the grid to the datatable, I can easily filter the contents using the Filter property of the data binding source, BUT I also need to be able to display only t he first 20 rows put of hundreds.
How can I limit the data bound to the grid? Any way to mention a TOP 20 or a LIMIT like in MySQL for the data source?

Also, the datatable that I bind to gets updated real-time: some rows are inserted, some updated and some deleted based of various scenarios...

Thanks in advance for any ideas or solutions!

Andrei

Comment: Maybe you can use some ideas from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891377/wpf-datagrid-max-rows?

Comment: *First* by what criteria? Whenever you want *the top (x)*, you need to also define by what sort criteria those rows should be sorted to find the top (x) rows....

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just making a view for it and binding the datagrid to it? Simple

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM table
```

would do the trick.

Comment: A `TOP 20` without an `ORDER BY` is typically rather pointless - `TOP` by what sort criteria?

Comment: Yeah I saw your previous comment on this question. I am pretty sure, that if AndreiC wants to use the TOP 20, he knows what he does the ordering on and simply didn't mention that. Thus I did not include it to my answer either :)