# Number of rows in a dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have implemented an editable dataGrid, where the user can type some values. The point is that, I only want a single row, but the dataGrid keeps adding an extra row, when the first row is filled with values and the "tab" key is pressed. I have even set the property:

```
CanUserAddRows="False"
```

But then, no rows are displayed in the dataGrid and I'm not able to enter any values.

My XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,373,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" Height="90" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" CanUserAddRows="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vare nr.:" Binding="{Binding Varenr}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Kolonnenavn" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox  Name="comboBoxUpdate" SelectedItem="{Binding Kolonnenavn}">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Navn" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Varenr"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Enhed"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Stkpris"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Konto"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Dato"/>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nyt Værdi" Binding="{Binding Nytværdi, StringFormat='{}{0:0.####}'}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm binding the typed values to an ObservableCollection.

XAML.CS:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    dataGrid2.ItemsSource = users;

}

public class User
{
    public string Varenr { get; set; }

    public ComboBoxItem Kolonnenavn { get; set; }

    public string Nytværdi { get; set; }
}
```

How do I handle this ?.

Comment: Have you tried setting `CanUserAddRows` to false after you've added the first row? You can always reenable it when needed.

Comment: How is that possible ?. The row is added, when I'm running the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the ability to add more than one row with a trigger like this:

```
<DataGrid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
```

Comment: Hi Eirik. I have directly added the snippet in my dataGrid XAML, but nothing changes.

Comment: You can try setting the `ItemsSource` for the `DataGrid` with a binding. I had to add a dummy `DependencyProperty` and bind the items source to it for my test to work.

Comment: Can you post the example please ?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891377/wpf-datagrid-max-rows

Thank you all the same